# Default values not appearing when using cascading parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008

[image]

I have setup a cascading parameter query.
Family > Group > Product

I'm able to set "AllType" as the default value for the last parameter "Product".
But I'm not able to set "TIJ2x" as the default value.

All the parameters are populated via a query dataset, specified under "available values".

Why is it working for "Product" parameter and not the "Family" parameter?
Is it because "Product" is the last cascading parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is really crazy. It turns out the problem was NOT because of SSRS.
But because the value stored in the database has WHITESPACES at the end.
It's not 'TIJ2x' but 'Tij2x      '

Once I changed the default value to the one with WHITESPACES, it starts showing up fine.

Thank God, managed to find this crazy bug.

Comment: I thought of removing all trailing whitespaces from the databases, it turns out this is by design. search for ANSI_PADDING.All the varchar columns are padded as such. 

But that doesn't affect when querying via SQL, because trailing whitespaces are ignored in SSMS.

Comment: Unfortunately, BIDS visual studio, doesn't ignore whitespaces automatically. Hence, this problem.

But if you set the default value via the web interface, it does ignore whitespace.